# PersistJS: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'init'

Tags: javascript

In my current code I am recieving the following error from PersistJS:

> Line 829 Persist.js: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'init'

This happens when I use any function, in my example I am doing:

```
var store = Persist.Store('test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js) documentation you are missing `new`

```
var store = new Persist.Store('test');
```